# Condensing output with python and multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, multicore, pickle

so I've been writing numerical stuff with numpy and multiprocessing for some time now. It works ok, but I'm having trouble collecting the results. I've done it in the following way, I take a queue for input and one for output. The program reads the parameters from the input queue, processes it and then puts the result into the output queue. Later on in the main process I read it out from the queue and pickle it. Something like this:

```
def fun(inp,outp):
    while True:
        try:
            params = inp.get(block=False)
            results = runprocess(params)
            out.put(results,block=False)
        except Empty:
            break
```

later on in the main loop i do the following:

```
for p in processes:
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    p.join()

while True:
     try:
          out = outp.get(block=False)
          a[i] = [out]
     except Empty:
          break

 fi = open(filename,"w")
 cPickle.dump(fi,a)
 fi.close()
```

But somehow, one of two things always happen: either the pickle comes out empty, or the processes hang up and stay running, using 0% cpu (in the beginning they go up to 100%, it's basically number crunching). Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Ok, so I've redone it with Pool.map(). Just so everyone knows how I got it to work here's the snippet:

```
    ncpus = mp.cpu_count()
    out = dict()

    params = [(a,p) for p in np.arange(0.0,2.0,0.1) for a in np.arange(0.001,2.0,0.1)]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=ncpus)
    results = pool.map(runm,params)

    for i in results:
            sigs = np.zeros((order,order))
            sigsmf = np.zeros((order,order))
            sigseq = np.zeros((order,order))
            xs = np.array([])
            freqs = np.array([])
            [(a,p),sigs[:,:],sigsmf[:,:],sigseq[:,:],xs,freqs] = i
            out[(a,p)] = [sigs[:,:],sigsmf[:,:],sigseq[:,:],xs,freqs]
            print a, p, sigs[0,0]
```

Works like a charm, much easier to implement!

Thanks Ferdinand! I'm not sure how, but I think we can close the question now!

Comment: Is 'i' getting incremented somewhere else?

Comment: You might want to consider using the simpler `Pool.map()` interface that handles all the boring details for you: `results = pool.map(runprocess, input_parameters)`.  See http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map

Comment: I'm not actually using i, I'm using a dictionary, so that's not the problem ;). I'll look into the pool interface! Thanks!

Comment: This means I'll have to fromat my input_parameters as a list, right?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you have block=False. When the collector tries to get data from the queue, it doesn't find it there immediately. So Empty exception is raised and it breaks out of the loop

While getting data from the input list, you can specify block=False as its a prepopulated list, I assume. However, the output queue is being built at runtime. So when you are trying to get data from it, its possible that its empty as the input process is taking longer to process.

If you know the length of the input queue, then you could try and block the output queue qet indefinitely. If not, then I would suggest that you block for a timeout.

Comment: Actually, I'm calling start and join in between, so it shouldn't be a problem, I think at least. I'll edit it above to clarify!

Comment: @Alex - It still is a problem. Try changing your code according with the answer above. Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a `timeout` in at least the `get` calls, and remove the `block`. In your current configuration, if no item is available in when calling the `get`, you will get the `Empty` exception, breaking out of the loop. If you are depending on a different thread to fill that queue and it doesn't fill it up in time, it will exit the loop prematurely and yield an empty result. Likewise, the `put` might hang because the queue is full, thereby hanging your program.

So, use something like this:

```
params = inp.get(timeout=1)
out.put(timeout=1)
```

Comment: Actually, the inp queue is prepopulated before calling the processes, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @AlexS: okay, then I need a bit more context, like how your threads are running w.r.t. each other. You current `start` and `join` them directly after each other, while reading out the queue after that. Also, as Nathan mentioned is his comment, you are currently assigning your results in `a[i]`, without incrementing `i`.

Comment: Ok, I should have added more context, I've rewritten it to use Pool.map(), as I'm actually just distributing parameter space! Thanks for the answer though!